# Scala external properties like Config-server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spring-cloud

Am new to Scala, we are planning to implement a new application with Scala/Spark. Is there a way that we can have external properties file which is similar to spring cloud config server?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "external" you mean on a different server.

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#loading-default-configurations

There is no built-in support yet, but two options:

- As a "pre-step", download the configuration file to `SPARK_CONF_DIR` on the master, prior to `spark-submit` (or use `--properties-file  customconfig.conf` as an argument to `spark-submit`)
- Write a custom entrypoint in your application, which requests the file from the external server and loads it using [Properties.load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: Thanks for the information, will try that way..just wanted to understand if we have anything similar to config-server